# Updating an Activity from an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

So I'm an iOS developer learning android, and I'm having a difficult time understanding some things. Right now I have a datamanager class. In that class it has an AsyncTask to update the data. OnPreExecute I pop an activity to show it is updating. I understand I could use extras to pass initial information to the UpdateActivity. My problem is I'm not sure how to send new information in OnProgressUpdate. Here is my code widdled down:

```
    private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Integer,String,Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        isUpdating = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        //My BG Code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Remove updating view
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext,UpdateActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: "...I have a datamanager class. In that class it has an AsyncTask...". Am I right in thinking your 'datamanager' class is not an Activity? If so, then you're not using AsyncTask in the way it is designed to work best.

Comment: You would be correct. It is not an activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AsyncTask is designed to work best when nested in an Activity class.

What makes AsyncTask 'special' is that it isn't just a worker thread - instead it combines a worker thread which processes the code in `doInBackground(...)` with methods which run on the Activity's UI thread - `onProgressUpdate(...)` and `onPostExecute(...)` being the most commonly used.

By periodically calling `updateProgress(...)` from `doInBackground(...)`, the `onProgressUpdate(...)` method is called allowing it to manipulate the Activity's UI elements (progress bar, text to show name of file being downloaded, etc etc).

In short, rather than firing your 'update' Activity from an AsyncTask, your update Activity itself should have a nested AsyncTask which it uses to process the update and publish progress to the UI.

Comment: I guess to me it seems better to have one class manage all data, and another manage the UI. But with android that is not the case? Does this mean I need to create new instances of my database helpers in the update class then? I think I see how this can be done, It is just different to me.

Comment: @mouser: The way I've done it for my current app is I have a 'db helper' class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper. I also extend the Application class which maintains a static reference to a single instance of the db helper. This means that all Activities etc can access the helper by using MyApp.dbHelper

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1) Pass an instance of activity to your AsyncTask constructor in order to invoke some method on it:

```
new MyTask(this).execute();
```

So, you can do:

```
  public MyTask (Activity activity) {
   this.activity = activity;
  }

  public void onPostExecute(...) {
   activity.someMethod();
  }
```

2) Pass a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instance and send message from onPostExecute() to the activity.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand, is how do I get the instance of the activity? Also, is one of these methods better than the other?

Comment: See the updated answer. Also, handler is better for many reasons. One of them is that you hide the implementation details of the activity from another class thus lowering the coupling.

Comment: I'm attempting the first method and it is not working so well. This is what I have in onPreExecute, the second line makes it crash:
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext,UpdateActivity.class);
    updateActivity.startActivity(myIntent);